# Core Loation not outputing current location

Tags: xcode, core-location, reverse-geocoding, currentlocation

I've been working on a app that displays the current location of the user in a UILabel using the core location framework in Xcode When a button is clicked the app calls the CLLocationManager that gets the users latitude and longitude. I also included reverse geocoding to present the coordinates in a human readable form. I have this code here.

Header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController   <CLLocationManagerDelegate> 

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitudeLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *longitudeLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *addressLabel;
- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender;

@end
```

Implementation file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController {
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}



#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to     Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {
    _longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    _latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",     currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}
}


@end
```

I got this output

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 15
```

Comment: A line is causing the issue? Because this message should be the equivalent of "kill -15", so user killed the app.

Comment: yea i misunderstood that line. There is no output actually when i run the app. when i click the Button that was supposed to get the location, nothing happens. I think it is because i didn't request for authorization for the app to use the location services.